# Show character count for the current line on mode line

Tags: mode-line

I don't know how to display in the mode line a character count for the line I'm currently editing.

I tried searching on Google, but nothing came up, only for the whole document or for a selection.  I wanted it to count on its own without need for a manual selection.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```el
(setq global-mode-string
      '(:eval (format "%d chars" (- (line-end-position) (line-beginning-position)))))
```